# Chocolatey : Installing SQL SERVER DEVELOPER Edition throwing error

Tags: sql-server, command-line, installation, chocolatey

I'm trying to install SQL SERVER DEVELOPER EDITION in SQL Mode using Chocolatey.

```
 $pwd = [Guid]::NewGuid().ToString('N')

choco install -y sql-server-2017 "/IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /Q /ACTION=install /INSTANCEID=MSSQLSERVER /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD=$pwd”
```

Here is the error it throws -

> ERROR: Running ["E:\setup.exe" /IAcceptSqlServerLicenseTerms /Q /CONFIGURATIONFILE="C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\sql-server-2017\tools\ConfigurationFile.ini" /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="DESKTOP-HOR5C91\madhu" /SAPWD="f577e388131a4af3b3bad077fb874e02" /SECURITYMODE="SQL" ] was not successful. Exit code was '-2067919934'.

Any idea how to resolve the issue?

Comment: Have you runt eh installer manually to see what errors it throws? That is usually the first thing I do. That and search online for the Exit Code.

Comment: Is there an SQL Server instance already installed on this machine? Is there more information in the C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Setup Bootstrap\Log\Summary.txt file?